# The names of magic items/devices in the folklore/fairy tales of the English-speaking countries

Tags: word-usage, word-request, terminology

In folk stories and fairy tales of every nation, there appear certain magic items or devices that, being obedient to a hero's will, always help him and the goodness triumph.

In the Russian folklore, for example, the most popular ones, which I can think of, have always been the following (the definitions are entirely mine):

> "Шапка-невидимка" — a hat which, being put on, makes a man invisible;
>
> "Сапоги-скороходы" — self-running boots;
>
> "Скатерть-самобранка" — a table-cloth which produces all sorts of meal
>   and drinks according to its user's preference;
>
> "Ковер-самолет" — a self-flying carpet;
>
> "Живая и Мертвая вода" — the two kinds of water, one called "live"
>   and the other — "dead". The former heals the hero's wounds,  the latter revitalizes him;
>
> "Молодильное яблоко" — an apple which, having been eaten, turns the
>   old into the young.

My question is this:

Does any of the above-listed exist in the English language oral tradition? What are their names in English? What other magic items or devices can be often met in the English-speaking world's folklore and fairy tales?

Comment: This is a really good question, but I think it is more about culture than language equivalency. Anyway, "Ковер-самолет" could be a "flying carpet", as in Alladin stories, or "magic carpet" for example [*Magic Carpet Ride*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Carpet_Ride_(Steppenwolf_song)).

Comment: @user3169 Thanks awfully, but is there a culture without a language and vice versa? I'm asking about what exists in the English language in the form of a word and what can hardly be found in dictionaries unless you do know what to look for. I don't. Is it an off-topic request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, the names aren't particularly inventive.

> "Шапка-невидимка" — a hat which, being put on, makes a man invisible;

This would probably be an *invisibility hat* or *hat of invisibility*, compare to a [cloak of invisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_of_invisibility) (which is quite a common item).

> "Сапоги-скороходы" — self-running boots;

Compare with [seven-league boots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-league_boots), which make each step cover 7 leagues of distance (38.8km). Also compare with the [winged sandals of Hermes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talaria) in Greek mythology.

> "Скатерть-самобранка" — a table-cloth which produces all sorts of meal and drinks according to its user's preference;

I don't know of anything common that's similar to this, but it did remind me of the Land of Goodies from Enid Blyton's [*The Faraway Tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faraway_Tree) books – the Land of Goodies is a place where everything is made of delicious food.

> "Ковер-самолет" — a self-flying carpet;

Just a "flying carpet" or "magic carpet" in English. I imagine most people would think of [Aladdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aladdin) when you mention flying carpets.

> "Живая и Мертвая вода" — the two kinds of water, one called "alive" and the other — "dead". The former heals the hero's wounds, the latter revitalizes him;

I haven't heard of anything like this. Something more general would be [*potions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potion), magic concoctions which may have any number of effects. The term ["elixir"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elixir#Noun) is also for liquids which heal and give strength.

> "Молодильное яблоко" — an apple which, having been eaten, turns the old into the young.

Not a food, but compare with the [Fountain of Youth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_of_Youth), which is a fountain which makes young anyone drinking or bathing in its waters.

---

As for common English folklore, a very common story is [*Jack and the Beanstalk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_the_Beanstalk), where a young boy (Jack) barters for magic beans. During the night following the beans being planted, a giant beanstalk grows. At the top of the beanstalk, Jack finds a large castle inhabited by a giant. Jack steals from the giant, and the giant chases him down the beanstalk. Jack then fells the beanstalk, killing the giant and living happily ever after on his ill-gotten riches.

The phrase *"happily ever after"* is also a common element in many English-language folk stories.

An element in Scottish folklore is the kelpie, a water spirit that lives in lochs that is said to have the strength of many horses. These are particularly noteworthy due to the [massive statue called *The Kelpies*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/The_Kelpies%2C_at_The_Helix%2C_Scotland.JPG) that was built in Falkirk.

Comment: Thank you very much for a most interesting answer and for the links I'm going to explore as soon as I can -- it is already midnight here, time to turn in. By the way, I saw a Japanese cartoon based on the tale of Jack and the Beanstalk when I was a kid.